# Why is Buddha presented as an overweight man?

Tags: the-buddha

I am not trying to offend anyone of to be disrespectful, but I cannot help to notice that the images of Buddha always represent him as an overweight man.  In my culture an overweight person is associated with an healthy lifestyle.

So I am curious to know why Buddha presented as an overweight man?